# The solutions of $x^2+ax+b=0\pmod n$ in $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For every positive integer $n\ge 6$ which is not prime, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that the congruence equation $x^2+ax+b=0 \pmod n$ has more than two solutions modulo $n$. I have no idea to prove the above statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: $\pmod n$ in $\mathbb Z_n$ is redundant.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $(x-u)(x-v)\equiv 0 \pmod n$ can also hold for $x-u=k$ and $x-v=l$ if $kl=n$, not only for $x-u=0$ or $x-v=0$.

Comment: You're welcome.